# Retrieve VS2010 auto-assigned build numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to find out what the number is that the build process assigns to the * when I have the assembly version set to something like 1.0.0.*?

I've been looking at the "EnvDTE" namespace in the macros, but haven't been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute(vs.71).aspx) if you have a version number in the form of

> **major.minor.build.revision**

and specify

> 1 . 0 . * . *

then

> **major** = 1
>   **minor** = 0
>   **build** = build to be equal to the number of days since January 1, 2000 local time
>   **revision** = revision to be equal to the number of seconds since midnight local timeivided by 2